# Joomla! 3.8.13 - article manager add images doesnt work (wrong url)

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

we have a Joomla! 3.8.13 on https
When I go to the article manager (default- tinymce) and try to add an image, then i see a whitescreen in the modal window. The reason is that it sends the request to http instead of https (admin uses https), so mixed content error

this is the url it sends the request to:
http://url/administrator/?option=com_content&view=articles&layout=modal&tmpl=component&d33ccba6239ca044b81e08cdb65a6f71=1&editor=jform_articletext

would be grateful for a hint :) thanks

Comment: As a general troubleshooting tip, issues can often be fixed by running a backup, updating all third party extensions and Joomla to the latest versions. Joomla 3.8.13 is several versions behind the current version 3.9.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue, the problem turned out to be non-standard .htaccess file

When clicking the image button, tinymce open an iframe thus making a request to https://url/administrator/index.php?..
and the server redirected http://url/administrator/?.. (with http and without index.php)

it then redirected back to https (as the force ssl was set in admin), but the browser already threw a mixed-content error

so changing the .htaccess to a standard joomla file fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Just for a hint. Since these links in article editor are created within Joomla with adding a JPATH_BASE at the beginning of the url thus most probably in Admin **global configuration->server** settings you should set **force SSL** to `Entire site` value. Then the link should automatically be `https` for the modal window in the editor. I hope it will solve your issue.

[image]